# ehcache spring annotation logs tracking

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jboss5.x, ehcache

I had integrated ehcache-spring-annotation jar with spring mvc 3.0.3 and spring secuirty 3.0.5 deployed on jboss

I can't see any ehcache logs as referred http://blog.goyello.com/2010/07/29/quick-start-with-ehcache-annotations-for-spring/ but I am not getting any error.

I have xmls defined as decibel-servlet
decibel-context 
decibel-security 
web.xml

my log4j.properties -----------------------

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%c]: %m%n

log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO

Answer (score 2):

Try adding something like these to your log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache=DEBUG 
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache.config=DEBUG 
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache.distribution=DEBUG 
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache.code=DEBUG
```

Comment: getting now 23:16:40,328 INFO  [STDOUT] DEBUG [net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper]: C
acheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'messagesCach
e'.

Comment: my ehcache.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" />
    <cache name="messageCache" maxElementsInMemory="10" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />
    <cache name="messagesCache" maxElementsInMemory="10" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />
</ehcache>